# Material UI Modal - default black border on render disappears on inspect

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Thanks for any thoughts on the subject.

I'm trying to work with the Material-UI Modal component. As shown in the picture below, there is always a black border on render.
I have tried

- removing it with custom useStyles and applying it to Paper, Modal, as well as the inner divs
- default CSS, (border:0 etc) with Paper, Modal etc.

[image]

The interesting thing is that when I click on the inspect tools, or when I focus the modal, the border disappears and leaves me with the style I desire until I re-render.

[image]

I greatly appreciate any suggestions or feedback, I'm new to Material UI and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your code in your question and include a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I'll do so next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This borders are added by browser, another one is defined in paper.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 400,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    outline: 0, // Disable browser on-focus borders
    //border: '2px solid #000',  // Remove black border of css
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));
```

With this changes I have removed them from [the sandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/c2rih?file=/demo.js:388-731).

Comment: Thank you! It seems like I was placing my styles in the wrong area, I greatly appreciate the help and the example provided.